# Grouping SQL columns from one table

Tags: sql-server

I am currently having difficulty getting the correct values from my table. Here is my table

NOTE: The column `Status` has 3 possible values (Cleaned, Unclean, Closed)

```
    +-----------+-------------+--------+------------+
    |ApplicantID|ApplicantName| Status |  HireDate  |
    +-----------+-------------+--------+------------+
    |     1     | John Smith  |Cleaned |08/26/2015  |
    |     2     | Alex Murphy |Closed  |09/12/2015  |
    |     3     | Oliver David|Cleaned |01/11/2015  |
    |     4     | Max Payne   |Unclean |03/18/2015  |
    +-----------+-------------+--------+------------+
```

The output I'm expecting and it should also be sorted by year.
For example I call all these records for the year 2015 which I get using the variable `@Year`.

NOTE: The column `Total` is the SUM of `Cleaned` and `Unclean`

```
   +---------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+
   |  Month  |  Cleaned  |  Unclean  |  Closed  |  Total  |
   +---------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+
   |  January|     1     |     0     |    0     |    1    |
   | February|     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   |  March  |     0     |     1     |    0     |    1    |
   |  April  |     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   |  May    |     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   |  June   |     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   |  July   |     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   |  August |     1     |     0     |    0     |    1    |
   |September|     0     |     0     |    1     |    0    |
   |  October|     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   | November|     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   | December|     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   +---------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

I can't seem to get the right code, for the sql this is my current code.

```
SELECT Month(HireDate) AS Month, COUNT(*) 
FROM Hires 
GROUP BY Month(HireDate)
```

I know my coding is wrong, because it is incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a list of numbers from `1` to `12` first to hold all `month`s. Then do a `LEFT JOIN` on `Hires` to make sure all missing months are accounted for. Then use conditional aggregation for the totals:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2757/1/0)

```
;WITH CteMonths AS(
    SELECT * FROM(VALUES
        (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
    )t(N)
)
SELECT
    Month   = DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, N-1,0)),
    Cleaned = SUM(CASE WHEN h.Status = 'Cleaned' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Closed  = SUM(CASE WHEN h.Status = 'Closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Unclean = SUM(CASE WHEN h.Status = 'Unclean' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Total   = SUM(CASE WHEN h.Status IN('Cleaned', 'Unclean') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM CteMonths m
LEFT JOIN Hires h
    ON m.N = MONTH(h.HireDate)
    --AND YEAR(h.HireDate) = @year --uncomment this line to filter for year.
GROUP BY m.N
ORDER BY m.N
```

---

If you want to include the YEAR:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2757/2/0)

```
;WITH CteMonths AS(
    SELECT * FROM(VALUES
        (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
    )t(N)
),
CteYears(yr) AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(HireDate) FROM Hires
),
CteAllDates(dt) AS(
    SELECT
        DATEADD(MONTH, m.N - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, y.yr - 1900, 0))
    FROM CteMonths m
    CROSS JOIN CteYears y
)
SELECT
    Year    = YEAR(d.dt),
    Month   = DATENAME(MONTH, d.dt),
    Cleaned = SUM(CASE WHEN h.Status = 'Cleaned' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Closed  = SUM(CASE WHEN h.Status = 'Closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Unclean = SUM(CASE WHEN h.Status = 'Unclean' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Total   = SUM(CASE WHEN h.Status IN('Cleaned', 'Unclean') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM CteAllDates d
LEFT JOIN Hires h
    ON MONTH(d.dt) = MONTH(h.HireDate)
    AND YEAR(d.dt) = YEAR(h.HireDate)   
GROUP BY YEAR(d.dt), MONTH(d.dt), DATENAME(MONTH, d.dt)
ORDER BY YEAR(d.dt), MONTH(d.dt)
```

If you want to filter for year, say `@year = 2015`, you can replace the previous ctes with:

```
;WITH CteMonths AS(
    SELECT * FROM(VALUES
        (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
    )t(N)
),
CteAllDates(dt) AS(
    SELECT
        DATEADD(MONTH, m.N - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, @year - 1900, 0))
    FROM CteMonths m
)...
```

Comment: Yes, because of the `SUM` aggregate.

Comment: Wait a minute...you're @wewesthemenace renamed!  I didn't know SO let you change usernames.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yup, it's me.

Comment: is the ";" in the start required?

Comment: It's not required at the start. However, it's required that you terminate the previous statement with `;`.

Comment: this kinda good :) but i got one more question :) where would i insert my variable "@Year" to get only records in the year 2015 or any other year? thanks :)

Comment: I think  `The Column "Total" Is The SUM of "Cleaned" and "Unclean"` was not accounted in the solution or am I missing something!

Comment: @DeepanshuKalra, oops. didn't catch that. Thanks!

Comment: @FelixPamittan thanks :) i will try it now :) and also... the Column "CLOSED" is not part of the Column "TOTAL" ;)

Comment: Cheers, +1 for the Year part.

Comment: I'am getting the error "Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow "

Comment: Where? What query did you use?

Comment: @FelixPamittan i cant make a complete code :( The First One Was Spot On! Perfect! But I Need The YEAR Filter :(

Comment: You can always use the first one, and add another join condition on `YEAR(h.HireDate) = @year`.

Comment: @GabrielValdezTimbol, can you post your query on one of my fiddles?

Comment: ahhh :) i will try it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87952/discussion-between-felix-pamittan-and-gabriel-valdez-timbol).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create `TEMP` table with values from `1` to `12` (numbers of months) and `JOIN` your table with `TEMP` table. To achieve values as columns names you can use `PIVOT` or `CASE`. You can do It in following:

```
INSERT INTO #Months VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)

SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, m.Id-1, 0)) AS [Month]
       , SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'Cleaned' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Cleaned] 
       , SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'Closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS [Closed] 
       , SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'Unclean' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Unclean] 
       , SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] IN ('Unclean', 'Cleaned') THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) AS [Total]
FROM #Test t
RIGHT JOIN #Months m ON m.Id = MONTH(t.HireDate)
GROUP BY m.Id
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
   +---------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+
   |  Month  |  Cleaned  |  Unclean  |  Closed  |  Total  |
   +---------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+
   | January |     1     |     0     |    0     |    1    |
   | February|     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   |  March  |     0     |     1     |    0     |    1    |
   |  April  |     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   |  May    |     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   |  June   |     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   |  July   |     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   |  August |     1     |     0     |    0     |    1    |
   |September|     0     |     0     |    1     |    0    |
   | October |     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   | November|     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   | December|     0     |     0     |    0     |    0    |
   +---------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

---

**DEMO**

You can test It at: <kbd>[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fb97d/4)</kbd>